# when will all ether be mined? Will there be a need for gas than?

Tags: ether

excuse me for my stupid question but when will all ether be mined? Will there be a need for gas than? Also, is there a max supply of ether?

Comment: You're confusing Ether with Bitcoin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As there is no max supply to Ether, answer is simple : ethers will never be completely mined.

However, for your information, the way of mining ether is going to change in the next forks as Ethereum Blockchain will move from Proof-of-Work to Proof-of-Stake .

You'll finde more information [Here](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Proof-of-Stake-FAQ)

Comment: Thanks. So the answer is there is an indefinite supply of ether. When I'm asking, As In hear with Casper ETHER mining will not be profitable anymore and no one would mine ether, so what happens with gas than? Will gas disappear, be much lower or else? Thanks, and sorry for my stupid questions :)

Comment: No, gas will be still used. 

About mining, the game changer is that investing in heavy infrastructure for mining will be useless, as with PoS, it's the staking that will give weight to miners. 

So, if you are an Ether millionnaire, you'll be able theorically ( i insist on that ) to run a node from a small computer and be an important node of the network. 

Gas will still be used as it will be used to reward miners for power consumption for computing the states.

Comment: Thanks! but do you think GAS will be lower for transactions? Maybe half it is today?

Comment: If you're referring to gas price in Ether, no one knows. It will depend on the number of transactions on the network with transactional capacity of the network, which is limited for now. 

If you're referring to gas consumption per instruction, i don't think it'll move as gas units represents power consumption for computing. You'll find an intent of listing the cost of instruction [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1n6mRqkBz3iWcOlRem_mO09GtSKEKrAsfO7Frgx18pNU/edit#gid=0)

Comment: "If you're referring to gas price in Ether" That's right. Thanks, I'm closing the answer.